# Get data from SQS Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a list of around 20 APIs and equal 20 SQS. 
Eg: API Name : XXX_API_NAME1 & SQS Name : YYY_SQS_NAME1
Same naming convention for remaining 19 APIs

Here if any failures in the any above APIs it will call it will send message to its respective SQS.

Now i need to fetch information from SQS like API Name,SQS Name & Timestamp and need to draft those information as an email to a recipient.

I have written triggering lambda for one SQS to receive msg like below,

```
sqs = boto3.resource("sqs")
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='YYY_SQS_NAME1')
```

I printed queue variable and got the below result.

sqs.Queue(url='https://queue.amazonaws.com/558485267243/YYY-SQS-NAME1')

Is this the right way? Is there any way to write a single lambda to achieve the above all 20 SQS names & attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to query the queue directly in the Lambda function like this. You should [configure the SQS queue as an event source for the Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html). Then the Lambda function will be invoked with one or more SQS messages in the event parameter.

If you want a single Lambda function to handle all the SQS queues, simply configure all of them as event sources for the Lambda function.